# How to calculate the maximal list size on available memory?

Tags: c#, list, tree, out-of-memory

I want to create a `List<MyClass>` with

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name;
    public List<MyClass> Children;
}
```

where the user decides how many objects should be created. Depending on the tree depth (all obejcts in the list have equal number of children) I get out of memory exception with different number of objects in the list. Is there a possibility to approximate the maximal number of objects?

Comment: such estimate would be extremely complex and unreliable... even if you can somehow calculate how many objects you would have not much space left for `Name` which is a string and needs also some memory...

Comment: you would need to take into account which framework version, bitness, overall system memory load etc. - and if the user happens to start another process/application after your calculation then your calculation would already be wrong...

Comment: How many objects can you create (approx) before OOM happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to approximate the maximal number of objects

No. There isn't such possibility.

Event if you could calculate something like `sizeof` for managed object, and get amount of free memory, you couldn't rely on this numbers, because managed code knows nothing about current memory fragmentation in its managed heap, it can't stop other processes in system (and other threads in current process) to query new memory allocations from system.